# how to dynamically display multiple images using asp.net from sql database using entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entity, asp.net-4.0

How can I display multiple images using Entity Framework in asp.net from the database.

I'm using DataList...

I'm a novice to asp.net, so could anyone give me a walk through.

Thanks

Comment: This ASP.NET Tutorial will guide you through the steps you need to perform: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/display_data_items_and_details

Answer (score 0):

You should store the images on the FileSystem (accessible from the Document Root) and store the image Path in the database.

Comment: It is very inefficient to store the actual bits of an image in a database. You will want to store the actual image in a directory such as `~serverdirectory/App_Data/uploads/images` and then in the database store the path to the image such as: ~serverdirectory/App_Data/uploads/images

Comment: I basically want to display a series of images which i have stored in the db, and retrieve them in the descending order of which is present in larger quantity and show it in the web page.

Comment: You will probably want to re-ask the question and include those details then.